# Active Directory Underlying Searcher Group Attributes from AccountManagement.Principal

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in .NET 4.5.

I am trying to get All groups and attributes from Active Directory as below code. But I have additional attributes defied as Key Value is System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult ,

**How can I get all attributes under System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal**

```
// create your domain context
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domain, _userName, _password);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
 var groupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(groupPrincipal);
foreach (var found in searcher.FindAll())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this with extension method as below but suggest me if there is any efficient way of doing the same job.

```
 public static class AccountManagementExtensions
    {
        public static String GetProperty(this Principal principal, String property)
        {
            var directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            return directoryEntry != null && directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property)
                       ? directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString()
                       : String.Empty;
        }

        public static String GetCompany(this Principal principal)
        {
            return principal.GetProperty("company");
        }

        public static String GetDepartment(this Principal principal)
        {
            return principal.GetProperty("department");
        }
    }
```